# while creating archetype getting following error

Tags: appfuse

D:\Training\workspace\vppsource>mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org
.appfuse.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-modular-struts-archetype -Darc
hetypeVersion=2.1.0-M1 -DgroupId=com.vmware -DartifactId=vpp
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'archetype'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Default Project
[INFO]    task-segment: [archetype:generate] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing archetype:generate
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] [archetype:generate {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[WARNING] Error reading archetype catalog http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Error transferring file: Connect
ion timed out: connect
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputD
ata(LightweightHttpWagon.java:143)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:11
6)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.apache.maven.archetype.source.RemoteCatalogArchetypeDataSource.ge
tArchetypeCatalog(RemoteCatalogArchetypeDataSource.java:97)
        at org.apache.maven.archetype.DefaultArchetypeManager.getRemoteCatalog(D
efaultArchetypeManager.java:195)
        at org.apache.maven.archetype.DefaultArchetypeManager.getRemoteCatalog(D
efaultArchetypeManager.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.archetype.ui.DefaultArchetypeSelector.getArchetypesB
yCatalog(DefaultArchetypeSelector.java:278)
        at org.apache.maven.archetype.ui.DefaultArchetypeSelector.selectArchetyp
e(DefaultArchetypeSelector.java:69)
        at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execu
te(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:186)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPlugi
nManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(Defa
ultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandalone
Goal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(Defau
ltLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHan
dleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegmen
ts(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLi
fecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:6
0)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)

```
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
```

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:233)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:323)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLC
onnection.java:860)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConne
ction.java:801)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection
.java:726)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon
nection.java:1049)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:373
)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputD
ata(LightweightHttpWagon.java:115)
        ... 28 more
[WARNING] No archetype found in Remote catalog. Defaulting to internal Catalog
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 46 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 09 16:11:07 IST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/28M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy server? You may need to configure proxy settings in your Maven settings.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
Adding this:

```
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.acme.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>myusername</username>
      <password>mypassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts></nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

to the bottom of my C:\Users\myuser.m2\settings.xml file fixed the issue.

See http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html for more details.